# WFFM field, adding custom attributes to checkbox field

Tags: wffm, sitecore-forms, accessibility

I have a use case where I need to add custom attributes to WFFM form fields. 
I have to add "aria-required" attribute to checkbox field if required is checked for a checkbox field.

I have created another class that inherits from wffm checkbox and have overridden the oninit() method.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        var form = WebUtil.GetParent<SimpleForm>(this);
        if (WFFMHelper.IsRequiredField(form, this.ControlName))
            this.checkbox.Attributes.Add("aria-required", "true");
    }
```

By this the "aria-required" attribute gets added to  tag which contains the checkbox. The "aria-required" attribute purpose is lost if added to  parent element instead of checkbox.

Please let me know there a way to add custom attributes to checkbox input directly.

Sitecore version 9.0.2
WFFM version 9.0

Comment: What version of WFFM and Sitecore are you using?

Comment: @AdamSeabridge : Sitecore version 9.0.2 and WFFM version 9.0.

Comment: Are you using MVC or ASP.Net WebForms?

Comment: ASP.Net WebForms. Not using MVC WFFM rendering as of now.